# Average of ratios ("on the fly") in excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this excel table used as a DB named "csv" :

```
Ticket  agent_wait  client_wait
1       200         105
2       10          50
3       172         324
```

I'd like to calculate the average of the ratios of the agent wait. `ration_agent` being calculated as `agent_wait  / (agent_wait  + client_wait)`.

If the table were like this:

```
Ticket  agent_wait  client_wait  ratio_agent
1       200         105          0.65
2       10          50           0.16
3       172         324          0.24
```

I'd just do the average of the `ratio_agent` column with `=AVERAGE(csv[ratio_agent])`.

The problem is that this last column does not exist and I don't want to create an additional column just for this calculation.

Is there a way to do this with only a formula ?

I already tried 
`=AVERAGE(csv[agent_wait]/(csv[agent_wait]+csv[client_wait]))` but it gives me the answer for only one line.

Comment: Do you want only 1 value or 1 value for each row?

Comment: Also, you want the average of `ratio_client` or `client_wait`

Comment: I want one value, the average of the ratio_client. But since that column does not exist, I want to calculate it on the fly with a function.

Comment: Do you want the ratio_client or ratio_agent? You keep saying ratio_client, but keep using ratio_agent in your calculations...

Comment: I assume you want averages of both ratios without having to have them for each row seperately. Am I right ?

Comment: This may sound silly, but isn't a formula based on a simple `=SUM(A:A)/SUM(A:A;B:B)` good enough for you in this case ?

Comment: Sorry it is indeed confusing. I wanted to simplify my issue but ended up making more complicated... Let me correct this

Comment: Did you try `=SUM(csv[agent_wait])/(SUM(csv[agent_wait])+SUM(csv[client_wait])))`?

Comment: @flyingdutchman I have edited my answer with some more information. Hopefully this helps you towards what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formula you have used, but you need to enter it as an array formula. What this means is, after entering the formula, do not press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The resulting formula will turn into this after you do that:

```
{=AVERAGE(csv[agent_wait]/(csv[agent_wait]+csv[client_wait]))}
```

And give your the value you are looking for. Use the correct columns (first `csv[agent_want]` to `csv[client_wait]`) if you are looking for the average `client_wait` instead.

---

[image]

---

It has come to me that your question might be an XY problem. Please take a read on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/80589/68593). It might help you decide on what you are actually looking for.

In brief if you want a measure of how much time:

- agents spend waiting, out of all the waiting between agents and clients, calculate the totals first and get the average of these totals. Outliers e.g. a special case where an agent spent lots more time on a client than the client themselves will heavily affect this measure. Use this measure if you want to know how much time agents spend waiting when opposed to how much clients wait.

  ```
  =SUM(csv(agent_wait)/sum(csv[agent_wait]+csv[client_wait]))
  ```
- agents each spend waiting on any particular call, calculate the ratios first then the average of these. Outliers will not affect this measure by much and give an expected ratio of time an agent might spend on any interaction with a client. Use this measure if you want to have a guideline as to how much an agent should spend waiting for each unit of time a client spends waiting.

  ```
  =AVERAGE(csv[agent_wait]/(csv[agent_wait]+csv[client_wait]))
  ```

Comment: [Another take on the subject after googling 'average of ratios vs ratio of averages'](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/64391.html). I'm not putting it in the answer because it's an external website and the contents might not indefinitely be available, and it's quite a long read which brings out about the same points as the ones I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It also wouldn't be correct to do the `=AVERAGE(csv[ration_agent])` calculation. An average of the average isn't the overall average. You need to sum the parts and then compute the overall average using those parts.

```
Ticket | agent_wait | client_wait | ratio_agent
------ | ---------- | ----------- | -----------
1      | 200        | 105         | 0.656      
2      | 10         | 50          | 0.167      
3      | 172        | 324         | 0.347      
Total  | 382        | 479         | ?????
```

The question is what goes in for the `?????`.

If you take the average of the `ratio_agent` column (i.e. `=AVERAGE(Table1[ratio_agent])`) then you get `0.390`.

But if you compute the ratio again, but with the column totals, like `=csv[[#Totals],[agent_wait]]/(csv[[#Totals],[agent_wait]]+csv[[#Totals],[client_wait]])`, then you get the true answer: `0.444`.

To see how this is true try this set of data:

```
Ticket | agent_wait | client_wait | ratio_agent
------ | ---------- | ----------- | -----------
1      | 2000       | 2000        | 0.500      
2      | 10         | 1           | 0.909      
Total  | 2010       | 2001        |
```

The average of the two ratios is `0.705`, but it should be clear that if the total agent wait was `2010` and the total client wait was `2001` then the true average ratio must be closer to `0.500`.

Computing it using the correct calculation you get `0.501`.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer!
But I am looking for the `0.39` (or `0.705`) value as I am interested in the average wait for each ticket and not the total average wait.

Comment: @flyingdutchman - Why? It's a meaningless figure once you turn it in to ratios. If you were dealing with the average difference in wait time then that would make sense. But an average of a ratio doesn't. What are you trying to convey?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now !
I'd like to know the average wait time of the agent

Comment: @flyingdutchman - That would be just `=AVERAGE(csv[agent_wait])`. But that doesn't like what you're asking about?

Comment: No indeed. I am looking for the average waiting time of a agent compared (or in regard) to the waiting time of the client. To have an idea of who waited the longer.

Comment: @flyingdutchman - is that then `=SUM(csv[agent_wait])-SUM(csv[client_wait])`?

Comment: Well the idea is to get a % of agent vs client waiting time. So in this case `-97` does not help me (unless I missed a step)

Comment: @flyingdutchman - Then to get a percentage you need to go back to my original answer - that's the correct way to compute this value.